# How to create graphs using scatter3D (Rstudio) in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, rstudio, scatter3d

I have added/installed packages for Rstudio to use in Jupyter notebook. However, I am unable to use scatter3D command in jupyter notebook. Tried installing R using conda prompt to add it to the jupyter notebook, also tried installing jupyter within R console.

I have the necesary packages installed and the rest of the R libraries seem to work fine (including ggplot) except the scatter3D. There's no error or warning displayed as well, hence I am unable to find the reason for the issue. Can someone help me out?

Screenshot: ggplot works fins but scatter 3D seem to run without any error but no output displayed.

Comment: Not everything has hooks that work in RStudio has them that are compatible with Jupyter seamlessly. RGL in particular can be difficult. I ran into it when trying to use early versions of Rayshader in Jupyter + R notebooks served via the MyBinder.org service. I had seen suggestions of running in R `options(rgl.useNULL=TRUE)` before installing the rgl package. That didn't help in headless situation I had but may help you. See [here](https://github.com/dmurdoch/rgl/issues/18#issuecomment-778689987) if you want to see that it isn't just scatter3D that has this issue because of RGL underlying it.

Comment: <continued> I noted that I did get 3D output working using `rglwidget()` based on https://gist.github.com/rpodcast/1a7552d5c6269d2fe488ef072ce64cfb . IIRC, that widget helped show rgl output when `rgl.useNULL=TRUE`. Plus I recall more evidence that using things based on RGL can be painful in regards to portability, [here](https://twitter.com/tylermorganwall/status/1401891304909512707).